# If less than 0 set to Null/Blank - SQL Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, datediff

I have the following expression running for my report.

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ClockedIn.Value, Fields!ClockedOut.Value)
```

Whilst this works for what I need it to, if a user forgets to clock out then I need it to set the hours worked value to be blank or come up with a message saying something like - "User not yet clocked out"

Is this simple to do?

EDIT: I have attempted the following - Is this the correct approach?

```
=IIf((DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ClockedIn.Value, Fields!ClockedOut.Value)<0 = TRUE, "User not clocked out", DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ClockedIn.Value, Fields!ClockedOut.Value)))
```

Currently this is erroring on the comma after TRUE

Comment: If you would like to have text value where also numeric value can appear, you should consider casting number to varchar(or char or string depending on platform). Otherwise you can just use Coalesce on result of DateDiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
 =IIf((DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ClockedIn.Value, Fields!ClockedOut.Value)<0, NULL, DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!ClockedIn.Value, Fields!ClockedOut.Value))
```

Comment: This errors, the red line is appearing under the comma after the 0.

Comment: remove one bracket from the end

Comment: put a opening bracket before Datediff and closing bracket before comma

Comment: Ahh that seems to have fixed it, I had to replace NULL with 0

Comment: probably it can